# Perl - concatenate files with similar names pattern and write concatenated file names to a list

Tags: perl, concatenation

I have a directory with multiple sub-directories in it and each subdir has a fixed set of files - one for each category like -

```
1)Main_dir
1.1) Subdir1 with files 

 - Test.1.age.txt
 - Test.1.name.txt
 - Test.1.place.csv
..........
1.2) Subdir2 with files 
 - Test.2.age.txt
 - Test.2.name.txt
 - Test.2.place.csv
.........
```

there are around 20 folders with 10 files in them. I need to first concatenate files under each category like Test.1.age.txt and Test.2.age.txt into a combined.age.txt file and once I do all concatenation I want  to printout these filenames in a new Final_list.txt file like

```
./Main_dir/Combined.age.txt
./Main_dir/Combined.name.txt
```

I am able to read all the files from all subdirs in an array, but i am not sure how to do pattern search for the similar files names. Also, will be able to figure out this printout part of the code. Can anyone please share on how to do this pattern search for concatenation? My code so far :

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use File::Spec;
use Data::Dumper;
use File::Basename;

foreach my $file (@files) {
print "$file\n";
}
my $testdir = './Main_dir';
my @Comp_list = glob("$testdir/test_dir*/*.txt");
```

I am trying to do the pattern search on the array contents in the @Comp_list, which I surely need to learn -

```
foreach my $f1 (@Comp_list) {
        if($f1 !~ /^(\./\.txt$/) {
        print $f1; # check if reading the file right 


 #push it to a file using concatfile( 
}}
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Hello @Borodin! Sorry for such late response to the answers you and rcedillo posted, pollen alert made weekend terrible! I just ran your script on my data and I wanted to post if or not I face any issues. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work for you. I've only tested it superficially as it would take me a while to create some test data, so as you have some at hand I'm hoping you'll report back with any problems

The program segregates all the files found by the equivalent of your `glob` call, and puts them in *buckets* according to their type. I've assumed that the names are *exactly* as you've shown, so the type is penultimate field when the file name is split on dots; i.e. the type of `Test.1.age.txt` is `age`

Having collected all of the file lists, I've used a technique that is originally designed to read through all of the files specified on the command line. If `@ARGV` is set to a list of files then an `<ARGV>` operation will read through all the files as if they were one, and so can easily be copied to a new output file

If you need the files concatenated in a specific order then I will have to amend my solution. At present they will be processed in the order that `glob` returns them -- probably in lexical order of their file names, but you shouldn't rely on that

```
use strict;
use warnings 'all';
use v5.14.0;    # For autoflush method

use File::Spec::Functions 'catfile';

use constant ROOT_DIR => './Main_dir';

my %files;

my $pattern = catfile(ROOT_DIR, 'test_dir*', '*.txt');

for my $file ( glob $pattern ) {
    my @fields = split /\./, $file;
    my $type = lc $fields[-2];
    push @{ $files{$type} }, $file;
}

STDOUT->autoflush;    # Get prompt reports of progress

for my $type ( keys %files ) {

    my $outfile = catfile(ROOT_DIR, "Combined.$type.txt");
    open my $out_fh, '>', $outfile or die qq{Unable to open "$outfile" for output: $!};

    my $files = $files{$type};

    printf qq{Writing aggregate file "%s" from %d input file%s ... },
            $outfile,
            scalar @$files,
            @$files == 1 ? '' : 's';

    local @ARGV = @$files;
    print $out_fh $_ while <ARGV>;

    print "complete\n";
}
```

Comment: Does `STDOUT->autoflush` need a module?  (A great answer, of course)

Comment: @zdim: `autoflush` is from [`IO::Handle`](https://metacpan.org/pod/IO::Handle). Its subclass [`IO::File`](https://metacpan.org/pod/IO::File) [loads automatically on demand](http://search.cpan.org/dist/perl-5.14.0/pod/perldelta.pod#Filehandle_method_calls_load_IO::File_on_demand) if you are using Perl v5.14.0 or later

Comment: Oh ... thank you very much!  Had no idea.  (We run v5.10 here :(.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Borodin, your solution works perfectly on my current set of that, but as you pointed, if I the files need to be in order of their names like Test1.age.txt, Test2.age.txt, Test3.age.txt, should I run a loop over file names and check the number using regular expression? Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 3):

I think it's easier if you categorize the files first then you can work with them.

```
use warnings;
use strict;

use File::Spec;
use Data::Dumper;
use File::Basename;

my %hash = ();

my $testdir = './main_dir';
my @comp_list = glob("$testdir/**/*.txt");

foreach my $file (@comp_list){
    $file =~ /(\w+\.\d\..+\.txt)/;
    next if not defined $1;
    my @tmp = split(/\./, $1);
    if (not defined $hash{$tmp[-2]}) {
        $hash{$tmp[-2]} = [$file];
    }else{
        push($hash{$tmp[-2]}, $file);
    }
}

print Dumper(\%hash);
```

Files:

```
main_dir
├── sub1
│   ├── File.1.age.txt
│   └── File.1.name.txt
└── sub2
    ├── File.2.age.txt
    └── File.2.name.txt
```

Result:

```
$VAR1 = {
          'age' => [
                     './main_dir/sub1/File.1.age.txt',
                     './main_dir/sub2/File.2.age.txt'
                   ],
          'name' => [
                      './main_dir/sub1/File.1.name.txt',
                      './main_dir/sub2/File.2.name.txt'
                    ]
        };
```

You can create a loop to concatenate and combine files

Comment: *"You can create a loop to concatenate and combine files"* I think that's the part the OP was having problems with!

Comment: Hi Borodin, he wrote "but i am not sure how to do pattern search for the similar files names". That's why I only wrote the code to can group files by type, at that point it's easier write a loop to do the concatenation I guess. Anyways nice answer

Comment: Yes, but there's also a loop `foreach my $file (@files) { ... }` which appears to do nothing but force a crash because `@files` doesn't exist. You can't just send everyone to an oncologist when they say they have cancer. Do some diagnosis!

Comment: "Can anyone please share on how to do this pattern search for concatenation?" 
;) I wanted help him.

Comment: Thanks @rcedillo for your detailed answer, it surely helps in learning how to group the similar file names, will come handy in my other problems. Thanks!